# No me funciona un api rest con spring boot

Tags: java, api, spring, spring-boot, rest

Tengo un error, estoy haciendo un login, que con login usuario me funciona el json por el Swagger ui, pero uno exactamente igual pero con login admin, no me funciona, hice los mismos pasos, voy a pasar el codigo primero del login usuario que funciona, luego el de que no.

USUARIO DAO

```
 static public Usuarios loginUsuario(String correo, String contraseña) {
    try {
        Connection conn = Conexion.obtenerConexion();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Usuario where correo = ? and contraseña = ?");
        ps.setString(1, correo);
        ps.setString(2, contraseña);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            int numRut = rs.getInt(1);
            String nombreU = rs.getString(2);
            String apellidoU = rs.getString(3);
            int numTelefono = rs.getInt(4);
            String correoElectronico = rs.getString(5);
            String direccionU = rs.getString(6);
            String contraseñaU = rs.getString(7);
            String productoU = rs.getString(8);
            String permisoU = rs.getString(9);
            return new Usuarios(numRut,nombreU,apellidoU,numTelefono,correoElectronico,direccionU, contraseñaU,productoU,permisoU);
    } catch (SQLException | SinConexionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

USUARIO CONTROLLER

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/loginUsuario/")
public void loginUsuario(@RequestBody Usuarios usuarios) throws Exception {
   Usuarios usuariosLogin = UsuarioDAO.loginUsuario(usuarios.getCorreo(), usuarios.getContraseña());

   if (usuariosLogin == null){
       System.out.println("Acceso denegado a USUARIO");
   }else{
       System.out.println("Acceso aprobado a USUARIO");
   }
}
```

HASTA AQUI FUNCIONA CORRECTAMENTE; va la base de datos y valida y retorna acceso aprobado a USUARIO, ahora aqui va el que presenta problema y recibe solo null, porque da solo denegado y estoy ingresando todo bien...

AdminDAO

```
    static public Admin loginAdmin(String correo, String contraseña, int rut) {
    try {
        Connection conn = Conexion.obtenerConexion();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Usuario where correo = ? and contraseña = ? and rut = ?");
        ps.setString(1, correo);
        ps.setString(2, contraseña);
        ps.setInt(3, rut);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            int numRut = rs.getInt("rut");
            String nombreU = rs.getString("nombre");
            String apellidoU = rs.getString("apellido");
            int numTelefono = rs.getInt("telefono");
            String correoElectronico = rs.getString("correo");
            String direccionU = rs.getString("direccion");
            String contraseñaU = rs.getString("contraseña");
            String cargo = rs.getString("cargo");
            String permisoU = rs.getString("permiso");
            return new Admin(numRut,nombreU,apellidoU,numTelefono,correoElectronico,direccionU, contraseñaU, permisoU,cargo);
    } catch (SQLException | SinConexionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

AdminController

```
       @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/loginAdmin/")
    public void loginAdmin(@RequestBody Admin admin) throws Exception {
    Admin adminLogin = AdminDAO.loginAdmin(admin.getCorreo(), admin.getContraseña(), admin.getRut());

    if (adminLogin != null){
        System.out.println("Acceso aprobado a EJECUTIVO");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Acceso denegado a EJECUTIVO");
    }
}
```

Si necesitan algo mas, por favor avisarme, agradezco sus respuestas, realmente llevo con este error muchas horas ya y no llego a una conclusion, ya que todo esta igual, tienen la misma estructura, gracias por sus respuestas :D

Comment: Y estás seguro que no hay una excepción que aparezca en la consola?
Porque según tu código en la función loginAdmin(), la única manera que retorne null es si hay una excepción, se imprime el stacktrace y luego retorna el null.
Como primera medida, te sugeriría que verifiques si rs.next() devulve true o false, y si es false retornes null.

Comment: Lo que me dice es: acceso denegado, siempre, como que siempre fuera null

Comment: Tal vex te parezca algo raro pero... en algún momento cierras tus recursos? Tus entidades son serializables y tienen su equals y hashcode?

Comment: No, pero lo que me deja duda, es por que con uno funciona y con otro no, si son casi la misma estructura

Comment: Acabo de descubrir el error, lo dejara por si alguien lo necesita luego, mi linea de código de admin  Admin adminLogin = AdminDAO.loginAdmin(admin.getCorreo(), admin.getContraseña(), admin.getRut());    la sustituí por    Usuarios adminLogin = AdminDAO.loginAdmin(admin.getCorreo(), admin.getContraseña(), admin.getRut());  es muy minimo el detalle